# Changing addEventListener variables' scope to global

Tags: javascript, scope, addeventlistener

I want variables from addEventListener functions to be taken into account when calculating the final, global variable. I know that by default they remain in local / block / function scope. **Can this be somehow worked around?** 
I am trying to calculate price (global variable) based on local variables from click events (input, drop-down list and 2 checkboxes). When I declare it I get a message that local variables are not defined. It’s understandable because event hasn’t happened yet. Even after  it does  I can read updated values of local variables in browser console but global variable still remains undefined.

Comment: It is very hard to debug code we cannot see. Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your file, declare the global var you want to mutate:

```
var EvilGlobalPriceVariable = 0
```

Then in the handlers, mutate that. Do that for every variable you want to affect in the handlers. Best to make it an object if you have more than one:

```
var EvilGlobalState = {
   mutateMeHandlers: 0,
   mutateMeToo: 0
}
```